# Beamer with bold frame titles: print also math expressions in bold

Tags: beamer, luatex, unicode-math

I am using a Beamer template, which uses a bold font for the frame titles. On some slides, I have also math expressions in the title. I would like also the math expressions to be printed in bold. I am using `unicode-math` and compiling with `lualatex`. In a LaTeX text document, which was compiled with `lualatex`, too, I had a similar problem with section titles. There I was able to fix it by using the snippet

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
```

from the internet. This doesn't help in the case of my Beamer presentation with different fonts. Therefore, I tried

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\symbfit}
\makeatother
```

However, in the case of my Beamer presentation, using this version of the snippet results in the error message `! LaTeX Error: \symbfitallowed only in math mode.`
So, it seems that adding this snippet to my presentation sources results in Beamer trying to use this math font for all parts of the title, which then causes errors. How can I fix this?

The full MWE is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Verona}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Roboto}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range=cal]{Stix Two Math}
\setmathfont[range={\lessapprox}]{Stix Two Math}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the "problematic" code
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\symbfit}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test \(f_1(x)\)}
    test slide
    \[f_1(x)\]
    \[\symbfit{f_1(x)}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the problematic code, the result looks like this:
[image: screenshot of a slide showing that math expressions in the title are not printed in bold, whereas the main part shows that the \symbfit command is working]

This illustrates nicely that, in principle, bold math is working.

Note that I don't want to add code in each `\frametitle` to make it work manually. I would like a general solution.

I am using TexLive 2019, as it is available from the package sources of Ubuntu 20.04.

*Edit on July 5, 23:* I corrected the statement about the use of the snippet in the case of the LaTeX text document. I used for that `boldmath` and not `symbfit`, which was stated falsely in the first version of the question. Thanks to user @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for questioning my statement, which led to this correction!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which versions are contained in your font, a simple `\boldmath` can be added to the frametitle font:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Verona}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test \(f_1(x)\)}
    test slide
    \[f_1(x)\]
    \[\symbfit{ f_1(x)}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your font does not support this, you can fake it:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Verona}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\setmathfont[version=bold,FakeBold=3]{Fira Math}

\setmathfont[range=up]{Roboto}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range=cal]{Stix Two Math}
\setmathfont[range={\lessapprox}]{Stix Two Math}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test \(f_1(x)\)}
    test slide
    \[f_1(x)\]
    \[\symbfit{ f_1(x)}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The workaround `\setmathfont[version=bold,FakeBold=3]{Fira Math}` from your second example is quite nice. However, it appears to me that `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}` is more or less (in terms of the effects) equivalent to ```\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother```, which works equally well if the FakeBold workaround is active. Nevertheless, I would be interested in understanding why ```\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\symbfit}
\makeatother``` causes an error in Beamer, while it works in text documents.

Comment: @user5415068 `\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\symbfit} ` will throw an error in other classes as well. You are mixing a macro which is only for text mode and a macro which is only for math mode - this can't end well.

Comment: You are right, in my text document I used ```\makeatletter \g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath} \makeatother``` and not the version of this code with `\symbfit`! I corrected my question accordingly and added at the end an explanation of the changes. Thank you very much for pointing this out!